# Randomize the ordering of rows in all queries on a SQL Server database for testing purposes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

SQL Server databases have arbitrary behavior regarding the ordering of rows in a result set, unless order is specified using `ORDER BY` (see [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)).

There's no easy way of determining what happens in the case where `ORDER BY` is not specified, but in practice it seems like it can often coincide with an existing index or primary key. Thus if there is a case where an `ORDER BY` on the primary key is missing, that bug can easily go undetected.

Is there a simple way of preventing this, such as forcing the database to randomize these results during testing as if `ORDER BY NEWID()` had been added to every data access?

Comment: `Is there a simple way of preventing this` is not clear.Can you explain in other word ?What are you trying to do ? It is 2 questions.

Comment: I doubt that a simple query of a single table would result in anything other than the equivalent of an `ORDER BY id`. Where the "random" behavior would begin to appear is when you have a more complex query with `JOIN` and/or sub-queries, or aggregate values. In such cases, the order that the query is performed is left to the database engine and could lead to an unexpected order if the `ORDER BY` clause is not specified.

Comment: I suggest moving this post to https://dba.stackexchange.com because this isn't a programming question, its a gnarly DB config question.

Comment: This is my opinion, your mileage may vary... From a performance standpoint you should avoid `order by` like the plague since in most cases the server has to fully materialise the result set before it can start ordering it to send to the connected client. Connected clients should be doing their own ordering on the client side, where the cost is easily distributed, and not depend on any specific ordering provided by the server. The bug is clients depending on server ordering.

Comment: No, there is no way to impose a "default" ordering on a result set.